# c# Firesharp - How to update a single value of an object?

Tags: c#, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fire-sharp

I have a c# project and I'm trying to update a single value of an object using [FireSharp](https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp). However, when I do, it deletes the other objects that are strings.

tldr question:

Is it possible to update only a single field of an object using Firesharp or do I have to include all fields when updating?

In the example on their GitHub, they set all fields with:

```
var todo = new Todo {
                name = "Execute SET",
                priority = 2
            };
SetResponse response = await _client.SetAsync("todos/set", todo);
Todo result = response.ResultAs<Todo>(); //The response will contain the data written
```

and then they update the fields with :

```
var todo = new Todo {
                name = "Execute UPDATE!",
                priority = 1
            };

FirebaseResponse response =await  _client.UpdateAsync("todos/set", todo);
Todo todo = response.ResultAs<Todo>(); //The response will contain the data written
```

[I know this is possible in other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48904039/is-it-possible-to-update-only-specific-data-on-my-child-on-firebase) so I feel like this should be possible in FireSharp.

My Case:

for example if I have a class like StudentProfile:

```
class StudentProfile {
   public string Firstname {get; set;}
   public string Lastname {get; set;}
   public int Age {get; set;}
}
```

when I uploaded to firebase, I use:

```
StudentProfile studentProfile = new StudentProfile 
{
   Firstname = "John",
   Lastname = "Doe",
   Age = 18
};

client.Set("Students/" + firebaseUserId + "/StudentProfile", studentProfile);
```

Now let's say I wanted to update the age. First I would get the info:

```
var result = client.Get("Students/" + firebaseUserId + "/StudentProfile");

StudentProfile student = result.ResultAs<StudentProfile>();
```

Now I want to update only the age. However, this is where it seems to update the `Age` but then delete the other values that are strings

```
int newAge = student.Age + 1;

StudentProfile updatedStudent = new StudentProfile 
{
   Age = newAge
};

client.UpdateAsync("Students/" + firebaseUserId + "/StudentProfile, updatedStudent)
```

Is it possible to update only a single field of an object using Firesharp or do I have to include all fields when updating?

Basically, it's a pain if I have to consistently write out all of the fields every time I want to update something.

Comment: i would try the github discussions page: https://github.com/ziyasal/FireSharp/discussions/categories/q-a

Comment: @Jazb, I never knew that existed before. Thank you for pointing that out. I will try there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to just expand the path on the left-hand side to the age, and then use `SetAsync`:

```
client.GetAsync(
  "Students/" + firebaseUserId + "/StudentProfile/Age", 
  newAge
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your values to update as `Dictionary<string,object>`. Then you can even update and push nested objects by defining the path as string.

Your example:

```
int newAge = student.Age + 1;

Dictionary<string,object> updatedStudent = new Dictionary<string,object>(); 
updatedStudent.Add("Age",newAge);

client.UpdateAsync("Students/" + firebaseUserId + "/StudentProfile, updatedStudent);
```

Adding something like this, would push a nested object to the jsontree:

```
    ...
updatedStudent.Add("Address/Street","Main Ave. 1");
client.UpdateAsync("Students/" + firebaseUserId + "/StudentProfile, updatedStudent);
```

Result would be:

```
    {
       "Firstname": "John",
       "Lastname": "Doe",
       "Age": 18,
       "Address":{
           "Street": "Main Ave. 1"
       }

    }
```